# Using the App.config file out of a shared project

Tags: c#, app-config, shared-project

How can I use the App.config file from a shared project in Visual Studio 2015 C# application?

```
 ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[pathKey];
```

This uses the App.config from the project you are in!

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by adding an `app.config` file as a solution item

*Right click on solution > Add Item > Application Configuration File*

And then add that shared file to required projects as references.

*Add Item > Add Existing Item > Add As Link*

[image]

Ensure that the properties are set to:

*Build Action: Content*

*Copy To Output Directory: Copy if newer*

Be aware that when using this method the config file will not be compiled with the name of the assembly - you may have to load the configuration from file.

Comment: Well I can't select a .config type file when I right click on new item for the solution.

Comment: @Bayern in that case you can just call the file app.config and it will take the extension given.